# Interesting RAM hardware Issue

Tags: memory, motherboard, memtest86+

I am having an odd issue with my desktop computer.

I have 8 GB of installed system memory, (MSI 990FXA-GD80 Mobo and AMD FX-6300 CPU) and occasionally, usually after changing settings in BIOS and restarting, I'll suddenly get a whole bunch of memory errors. (I'm using memtest86+ to assess this.) It looks like an entire section of RAM has spontaneously gone bad! The even odder thing, though, is that I can fix it simply by turning off the computer, taking out both DIMM's, (I have two 4 GB modules installed, and the other 2 slots are empty) and putting them back in. I am completely stumped on this one, as I have never seen anything like it, and I was wondering if anyone had had any similar experiences. At first, this seemed like a simple issue with sketchy RAM, but the fact that removing and reinserting the DIMM's fixes it makes me suspect that something more complicated is going on.

Comment: Sounds like dirty contacts, e.g. skin oils on the DIMM's edge connector (caused by touching) or oxidation. Try cleaning with a "contact cleaner" or isopropyl alcohol.

Comment: Had plenty of contact issues but not recurring like that. Had issues with older motherboards and 4gb double-sided dimms, as the motherboards did not support that configuration.

Comment: Adjust the ram in the bios, the divisor and/or timings and try again, like set ram to 1600, Get some extra cooling going on them with a slopped in fan for some time. to cover that possibility.   New motherboards can/do adjust ram settings when the board will not post with the settings made, so there can be stuff going on behind the scene that your not ever in charge of. Tweaking the ram just right might get it working.  and it could be just ram gone bad, not working in dual, test with one module?

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone. It's probably worth cleaning the contacts, just in case. Also, I'm not doing anything weird with RAM timings in the bios; it's 1600 Mhz RAM and I believe that's what I have it set to. Plus, the cooling is pretty good; the case has lots of fans, including one right above the RAM. Next time it happens I'll test with just one module and see if the problem is happening consistently with just one of them.

Comment: Are You sure it is necessary to take RAM out to fix an issue? I suspect system dosn't reset properly. So it may be enough to completely poweroff the system for couple of minutes (disconnect power cables).

Comment: this is probably a situation where a "double-post" is required to e.g. "memory training" etc, but it is not being triggered. Often, motherboards will double-post after a cold (hard) reset where power from the wall socket has been removed. google "cmos double-post boot"